# Trouble in calling web api Post method from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am calling web api post method from jquery ajax. It run fine when i am passing object with only string properties but showing null value when passing all of its properties including string,int and bool,

**Entity class**

```
  public partial class Pract_Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Nullable<decimal> Price { get; set; }

    public Nullable<double> Weight { get; set; }

    public Nullable<bool> isactive { get; set; }
}
```

**JS**

```
    var Pract_Product = new Object();
    //    Pract_Product.Id =  $('#Id').val(),
        Pract_Product.Category = $('#Category').val(),
        Pract_Product.Name = $('#Name').val(),
    //    Pract_Product.Price = $('#Price').val(),
     //   Pract_Product.Weight = $('#Weight').val(),
     //   Pract_Product.isactive = "1"

        alert('tested');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:4135/api/ProdService',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: Pract_Product,
            async: false,
            headers: { 'Password': pwd },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                debugger;
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
```

**API controller action**

```
// POST api/ProdService
    public HttpResponseMessage PostPract_Product(Pract_Product product)
    {
   //-- code for inserting object
   }
```

In above example i have commented properties with datatype other that string for the object, then this call working fine and giving proper string values both string properties and null for other properties. When I pass all values it gives me internal server error.I also tried using `data:JSON.stringify(Pract_Product)` but no resolution. Please help me out..

Comment: Is there an exception stack-trace anywhere? I don't know much of ASP.NET, but does the framework take care of converting URL-parameters into "decimal" or "boolean" representations within properties? If not, you're better of considering everything as a string and doing the appropriate conversion internally. Or you can override the set/get for each property to ensure you parse the value correctly.

Comment: Yes correct,I guess object datatypes are not matched from both end

Comment: Have you tried to only send all fields separately and let the Binder create the object?

Comment: And the value of `isactive` should be `true or false` not 1

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with parameters. Could you show the exception details?

Comment: @lnanikian :yes you are right. I corrected these parameter values it works for id and isactive parameter but not for wight and price which are decimal.

Comment: x.responseText =`"{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Property 'Price' on type 'ProductApp.Product.Prac+Product' is invalid. Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property with......."`

Comment: Then a custom Binder for this case will be required. As you send everything the custom Binder will ensure that each properties will have the correct type value

Comment: Can you please share how to achieve this

Comment: There is a good example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/605595/ASP-NET-MVC-Custom-Model-Binder) but my concern is about how to retrieve value from an Ajax call to assign values of your properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ASP.NET signature to accept an object as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostPract_Product(object model)
{
    // now convert from object to Pract_Product
    var jsonString = model.ToString();
    Pract_Product result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Pract_Product>(jsonString);
    //-- code for inserting object
}
```

Comment: I tried this but `jsonString` does not contain the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in serializing **decimal variables** which have **0 in decimal part** to **JSON**.

So **1.23 will be correctly serialized to 1.23**, but **1.00 will be serialized to 1**.

To solve this problem you can basically do:

**- Convert decimals to fixed format:**

`Pract_Product.Price = $('#Price').val().toFixed(2);` (Where 2 is a number of digits in decimal part).

Documentation for [**JavaScript toFixed()**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

**- Create custom model binder (as it recommended [here](http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/)):**

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                    ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

And register it in Application_Start of Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());   
}
```

---

Also I would recommend you to add `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` to your ajax request.

Used articles: [**JSON and .NET Decimals**](http://blog.dontpaniclabs.com/post/2013/02/06/JSON-and-NET-Decimals), [**ASP.NET MVC3 JSON decimal binding woes**](http://digitalbush.com/2011/04/24/asp-net-mvc3-json-decimal-binding-woes/) .